# faker and factory_girl troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, faker

Good day!
I'm trying to create random values when creating model in my tests. Using factory_girl  and faker gems

as of my gemfile.lock

```
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
faker (1.6.1)
```

I define factory as follows

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :action do
    name Faker::Internet.email
    id Faker::Number.digit
    ip Faker::Internet.ip_v4_address
    old_value Faker::Number.number(7)
  end
end
```

but in my tests when i try to create objects, they have the same attributes.

```
> create :logger
 id: 17,
 new_value: 3133860,
 name: "fidel_murazik@gibson.biz",
 ip: "118.247.64.189",
 created_at: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 09:12:50 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 09:12:50 UTC +00:00>
```

and the second time

```
    > create :logger
     id: 18,
     new_value: 3133860,
     name: "fidel_murazik@gibson.biz",
     ip: "118.247.64.189",
     created_at: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 09:12:53 UTC +00:00,
     updated_at: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 09:12:53 UTC +00:00>
```

One more time - I'm trying to get via Faker gem random valid attributes for factory_girl every time I create a new object.
Can you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sequence` to generate different data every time running:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :action do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "user_#{n}@factory.com" }
    sequence(:id) { |n| Faker::Number.digit + n }
    ip Faker::Internet.ip_v4_address
    old_value Faker::Number.number(7)
  end
end
```

Btw `id` will be generated automatically, feel free to remove `id`!

Comment: This is not what I've asked. I'm talking about Faker